# SimHash general explanation and details

Tags: algorithm, duplicates

I'm trying to find a more detailed explanation of what SimHash is and what it does (how to implement it) . Help?

Can't seem to find a proper detailed explanation anywhere, only in general what it is, but not how the algorithm works or maybe some sort of implementation that'll help me understand it.

Comment: Original paper: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring04/cos598B/bib/CharikarEstim.pdf

Comment: I recently published a blog post about SimHash and a way to speed up the calculation that might help: https://engineering.dynatrace.com/blog/speeding-up-simhash-by-10x-using-a-bit-hack/

Comment: Lookup wikipedia, in external references you can find a link to the paper which describes it in detail.